# How can I remotely configure an XP computer to sleep after x minutes?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-access, electrical-power

I need to configure all of our XP computers to sleep after a few hours of inactivity. Doing this from control panel is easy, but I'd like to avoid having to visit each desk individually. Is there any way to do this remotely?

Comment: True inactivity? For example some programs like movie players prevent that even if there is inactivity.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're running Active directory, You can use [Energy Star's EZ GPO](http://www.energystar.gov/index.cfm?c=power_mgt.pr_power_mgt_ez_gpo) to manage a bunch of power-related features.